# regex help to parse data - how to get all the text in between two points

Tags: regex, parsing, make.com, integromat-apps

I've seen so many of these pages and received so much help over the years.
First time askign a question.

Basically, I use automation tools such as Integromat/Make/Zapier.

I have a csv file with a lot of data for a self-made booking system.

For the automation system to work, I will need to parse the data into "chunks" that I can map and add the proper functionality to.

The text looks as follows (but much longer of course):

BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20220301T023567Z
UID: xxx
DTSTART;TZID=Asia/Tokyo:20210630T110000
DTEND;TZID=Asia/Tokyo:20210630T160000
DESCRIPTION:\n--------\n同日入替 : false\n前回ゲスト数 : 1\n次
SUMMARY: xxxxx (xxx / xxx xxx
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20221105T072143Z
UID: xxx
DTSTART;TZID=Asia/Tokyo:20210501T110000
DTEND;TZID=Asia/Tokyo:20210701T160000
DESCRIPTION:\n--------\n同日入替 : false\n前回ゲスト数 : 1\n次
SUMMARY: xxx (xxx / xxx xxx)
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20220905T023143Z
UID: xxx
DTSTART;TZID=Asia/Tokyo:20220227T110000
DTEND;TZID=Asia/Tokyo:20220227T160000
DESCRIPTION:\n--------\n同日入替 : true\n前回ゲスト数 : 2\n次回
SUMMARY:★ xxx (xxx / xxx xxx)
END:VEVENT

I need the parts that need to be together as parts as:
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20220301T023567Z
UID: xxx
DTSTART;TZID=Asia/Tokyo:20210630T110000
DTEND;TZID=Asia/Tokyo:20210630T160000
DESCRIPTION:\n--------\n同日入替 : false\n前回ゲスト数 : 1\n次
SUMMARY: xxxxx (xxx / xxx xxx
END:VEVENT

BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20221105T072143Z
UID: xxx
DTSTART;TZID=Asia/Tokyo:20210501T110000
DTEND;TZID=Asia/Tokyo:20210701T160000
DESCRIPTION:\n--------\n同日入替 : false\n前回ゲスト数 : 1\n次
SUMMARY: xxx (xxx / xxx xxx)
END:VEVENT

BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20220905T023143Z
UID: xxx
DTSTART;TZID=Asia/Tokyo:20220227T110000
DTEND;TZID=Asia/Tokyo:20220227T160000
DESCRIPTION:\n--------\n同日入替 : true\n前回ゲスト数 : 2\n次回
SUMMARY:★ xxx (xxx / xxx xxx)
END:VEVENT

---

Meaning that everything in between two specific points, starting with "BEGIN:VEVENT" and ending with "END:VEVENT" needs to be separated.

I have been trying to learn regex but as I can see many others are saying online, its not the most welcoming thing ever .. Im struggling hard.

Answer (score 0):

You may try matching on the following pattern:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT.*?END:VEVENT
```

### Demo

The above regex should be run in dot all mode (with the `/s` flag) so that `.*` can match across all lines in each event.

Comment: My saviour!

yes this worked perfectly. 

thank you so much for the help.

Comment: @シンニエンSinnien please click on "accept answer" if his answer helped you.